# Самовызов функции с параметром: a is not defined

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код JS:

```
var а = {};

+function b ( a ) {
    a.a = 10;
    а = null;
}( a );

console.log(a);
```

Выводится следующие:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Но почему? ведь переменную мы объявили глобально, да еще и `var`.

`+function` сокращенная запись `(function b(a) {})();` или `(function b(a) {}());`.

Comment: Потому что латинская `a` и кириллическая `а` — это два разных символа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"a" - из разных алфавитов в этих двух строчках:

```
var а = {};
console.log(a);
```

```js
var a = {};

+function b ( a ) {
    a.a = 10;
    a = null;
}( a );

console.log(a);
```